# How to make an Firefox like tabcontrol in c sharp?

Tags: c#, tabpage

Does someone know how I could extend and TabPage so that there is a X visible on an active tab, that when pressed, closes the tab /ask if the tab should be closed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TabControl.DrawMode property to implement custom drawing.  There's a good example of a DrawItem event handler in the MSDN Library article.  Use Graphics.DrawLine() or DrawImage to draw the x.  Use the MouseUp event to detect a click on the x.  You'll need the GetTabRect() method to find out which tab was clicked.  And narrow down the location to verify that it was near the x.